# How to get tag <head> description product in shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want get tag head in product description [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ19D.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXaef.png

into tag li

so how do i do ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxNvG.png

Comment: Please post code snippets instead of screenshots, for more info please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, first you should add specific character at before and after of head tag

for example, `<!-- split-production --> Production Details <!-- split-production -->`

Then you can split by `<!-- split-production -->` like this `{% assign productDescription = product.description | split:"<!-- split-production -->"%}`

Then display it as array! `{{ productDescription[0] }}` etc...[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to select the text and create list with the list option.
2. Select text which you want to add in to the heading tag.
   That's how you can add head tag in to the li tag.[image]